# Laravel Authentication Security

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm reading through the authentication documentation for Laravel on the following link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication

It seems like only 3 database columns are required; username, password, and remember_token.

Is this method of authentication highly secure or would there be a stronger alternative using Laravel? I'd love to get some more insight into this as I have always been using the default username, password session based login and have heard horrible things about session-hijacking etc but am looking to keep up to the trends!

Comment: Give [laravel socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) a glanceover. You may like what you see. This way you can just store a token relationship between a user and their facebook/gmail/github/whatever. You could always allow plain text authentication as a fallback.

Comment: Laravel doesn't use PHP default session handling, it has it owns. It is pretty much secure to abuse from outside.

Comment: This issue on GitHub could be useful: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1462